# Blog installed in subdirectory but need to create pages in root. How to use permalinks?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Our companies blog is installed in `/blog`. Our permalink structure is `/%postname%/` so posts currently look like `https://www.domain.com/blog/post`

We've been asked to publish a series of guides which must be installed in `/buying-guides/` e.g. `https://www.domain.com/buying-guides/kittens` i.e. outside of the WordPress folder.

I thought the answer was to simply create a page called buying-guides and then create a page per guide as children. We then end up with URLs such as https://www.domain.com/blog/buying-guides/kittens. I then created an `.htaccess` rule in our root folder with

```
RewriteRule ^buying-guides/(.+)$    /blog/$1 [L,NC]
```

and it seems to be working beautifully! Until I realized that, there is more to it as WordPress is obviously not aware of the rewrite. For example, we use `the_permalink()` function to generate the link in our page titles and this now obviously generates the incorrect link (although it would still work, but we don't want customers too see any mention of `/blog/` when browsing the buying guides.

Is there a good solution to the above issue? Perhaps a filter than automatically changes all URLs just before the page is rendered from `/blog/buying-guides/` to `/buying-guides/`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [`the_permalink()` filter hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink)?

```
add_filter('the_permalink', 'remove_blog');
function remove_blog($url) {
    //only affects the permalink of pages
    if(is_page()){
        return str_replace('blog/', '', $url);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

In combination with your current rewrite rule in the .htaccess of your root directory.

Comment: Yes, that works great however it obviously affects all permalinks including our blog posts in /blog. To confirm, our blog posts are in /blog and our pages are in the root. Is there a way to limit this function to only pages?

Comment: You could use [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page), [is_single()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single), [is_singular()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) or any other of the [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: Thats works beautifully thanks! Just to confirm, the function name should be 'remove_blog' (not 'append_query_string') right?

Comment: Sorry for the 'append_query_string' name issue, I was copying from own code and forget to rename the function. Fixed.

Comment: Is this the answer for your question?